# trying to figure out how to perform an ajax call to prevent submit button from reloading entire page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this url page that reloads once the send key is submitted. I need to add an ajax call to call one line of text  which is the following

Your feedback is greatly appreciated..

I have placed that line in a div with `id="fd-bk"`

```html
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/__${page}__}" th:object="${client}" class="contact-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-1">
            <div id="fd-bk" class="alert alert-info" th:if="${emailSent}">
                Your feedback is greatly appreciated.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" th:field="*{name}"
                   required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label for="email-cnt-rfl">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email-cnt-rfl" placeholder="Your Email"
                   th:field="*{email}" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" size="20"
                   required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label>Drop us a line</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message" th:field="*{message}"
                      required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <input type="submit" value="Send It!"
                   onclick="scrollSmoothToBottom()">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com//search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dperform+an+ajax+call) didn't answer your question?

Comment: no they didn't answer its 3 am here and i have to finish a project .. if you have  better tailored to my situation add it

Comment: SO is not a Finish My Project Service ... You can find a generic AJAX call example [in this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509329/1169519).

Comment: You don't have to read it through, the code fields on SO are pretty well recognizable, just scroll down to the example ... For your future projects, it would be useful to read the entire post, though.

Comment: isnt that all we do.  read, test and keep testing till we figure it out.. fix my problem mister so i can plug it in my code and move on.. its now 5 am and if i start reading through your code i might fall asleep

Comment: Not exactly, most of the developers are just writing the code, and the tests are made just to make sure the written code works in all use cases.

Comment: are you trying to tell me that all the code you have written is self improvised and that you have never read someones code and use that same code or some form of it to retrofit your situation... i find that hard to believe...

Comment: This goes a bit off-topic, but no, I have applied code examples every now and then, and I really appreciate generic examples, which are much easier to apply to my own purposes. Anyway, "_read, test and keep testing till we figure it out_" is not programming, it's studying, and that should not be done just before the deadline.

Comment: I won't miss my points if you'd read that answer of mine, and resolve your problem using the generic example (which actually fits to your requirements perfectly), and then vote up my answer = ).

Comment: ha.. if i read your answer and see how you made the OK message show before redirecting i will answer my own question and get my own brownie point

Comment: To promote generic answers, [here's a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709001/alternative-approaches-to-multiple-if-else-conditions#comment112659253_63709001) of a very specific solution. It's clear, that the "brilliant" bitmask solution can't be applied to other similar problems, such an answer wouldn't be useful for future readers. We're not here to spoonfeed solutions to askers, we're building "_a library of detailed answers to every question about programming._". Use the library, make a search, and find a generic solution you can apply, the basic skill of programmers.

Comment: i read your article it was nice; gave me alot of insight on the inner workings of <form></form> and i solved the problem using js and without having to use ajax i am not sure ajax  is the right solution..  i have seen this  xhr.open('POST', 'action_URL');
  xhr.addEventListener('load', e => { ... with ajax calls it works well when getting data back from the server which i am using java also it seems like ajax works well with callbacks .. so using ajax  is probably over kill here.. maybe im wrong.. but in any case thanks for the article you wrote

Answer (score 0):

include this makeCall() in the

```
<form>
<div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send It!"
                                   onclick="scrollSmoothToBottom()">
                        </div>
</form>


function makeCall() {
    const form = document.querySelector('#form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
         
        const message = document.querySelector('.hidden.alert-info');
        message.classList.remove('hidden');
         
    });
}
```